# How To Get Sum On Multiple Jsonb Values Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am running a cron each Weak and saving customers' data on a new table,
For a customer per month 4 records,
End of every month I am running a new cron and need to get the sum on customer data and save it on a new table to send some reports.

weak data is saved like this

```
[customer_id = 25
data {
  "body": {
    "aaa": 0,
    "bbb": 98,
    "ccc": 0,
    "ddd": 1,
  }
}
],
[customer_id = 25
data {
  "body": {
    "aaa": 22,
    "bbb": 22,
    "ccc": 22,
    "ddd": 12,
  }
}
]
```

since it is a JSON b column I couldn't get the sum

This is my code

```
 $summaryReport = summaryreport::all();
                   
 foreach($summaryReport as $report){
          
     $data['aaa'][$report->customer_id] = (json_decode($report->data)->body->aaa);
    }
     Model::insert($data);
    ``
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly filter your reports by using the collection method `where()`, to only include the correct users. From there you can sum on the collection summing all the data entries, but do it with the `closure` approach. Where you can fetch the data from the data structure, to call another `sum()`.

```
$reportData = collect(json_decode($report))->where('customer_id', $report->customer_id);

$reportData->sum(function ($item) {
    return collect($item->data->body)->sum();
});
```

This is simply an exercise in knowing and understanding collections methods and how to utilize them in a non standard data structure.

Comment: tks for the answer , i need to get sum based on the customer id, there are multiple cystomers

Comment: What would happen if there is two reports with the same customer id, as in your data example?

Comment: there will be multiple records for customer id - I need to get the sum of a customer id and save ai in a single record on the new table

Comment: I updated the answer, see if any error occurs but this should be very close to something that could work.